Spring Batch. DataSource must not be null
I created a new Spring project to test Spring batch in Java 17. The job is simple, print "Hello, World!".
My batch-job.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd">

    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="helloWorldTasklet" class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.MethodInvokingTaskletAdapter">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="helloWorldService"/>
        <property name="targetMethod" value="printHello"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="helloWorldService" class="com.test.batch.service.HelloWorldService"/>

    <batch:job id="helloWorldJob">
        <batch:step id="helloWorldStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="helloWorldTasklet"/>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
    
</beans>

My BatchConfig.java(Note: the setDataSource was not used and cannot be overriden as suggested here: Spring boot + spring batch without DataSource)
package com.test.batch.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {

    private final JobRepository jobRepository;
    private final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    public BatchConfig(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        this.jobRepository = jobRepository;
        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return new JobBuilder("helloWorldJob", jobRepository).start(step()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        TaskletStep taskletStep = new StepBuilder("helloWorldStep", jobRepository)
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                }, transactionManager).build();
        return taskletStep;
    }

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    }
}

My HelloWorldService.java
package com.test.batch.service;

public class HelloWorldService {

    public void printHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}

My App.java(also as suggested in link above. i added "@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})" here)
package com.test.spring.springbatch;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@ImportResource("classpath:batch-job.xml")
public class App implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job helloWorldJob;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        jobLauncher.run(helloWorldJob, new JobParameters());
    }
}

My pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.test.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>springbatch</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>springbatch</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>

The error i am getting when i run the application is, DataSource must not be null. can anyone help me please? The log is as below
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'app': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jobLauncher': Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncher' defined in class path resource [batch-job.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:787) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:767) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1421) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962) ~[spring-context-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
            at com.test.spring.springbatch.App.main(App.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobLauncher' defined in class path resource [batch-job.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1436) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            ... 19 common frames omitted
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [batch-job.xml]: DataSource must not be null.
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            ... 32 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: DataSource must not be null.
            at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
            at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:257) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.2.jar:5.1.2]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1835) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-6.1.7.jar:6.1.7]
            ... 39 common frames omitted


You are missing the datasource configuration, feel free to modify the following database configuration depdending on provider of your choice.
private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
        public DataSource getDataSource() {
            DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
            dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
            dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
            dataSourceBuilder.username("SA");
            dataSourceBuilder.password("");
            return dataSourceBuilder.build();
        }

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        // Update the job repository and transaction manager with the new data source if needed
        // Example:
        // jobRepository.setDataSource(dataSource);
        // transactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

